# Execute a function call in MATLAB GUIDE

Tags: matlab, function, matlab-guide

In MATLAB:

I have this independent function which runs optimal in the command line:

```
function datacollect()
filename = uigetfile('*.txt')
[col] = importdata(fileName)
long = columns(:,1)
lat = columns(:,2)
handles.long = long;
handles.lat = lat;
```

But when I make a function call inside GUIDE:

```
datacollect()
```

I get an error:

> > ??? Reference to non-existent field 'output'.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is a name collision between the `handles` variable in `GUIDE` that is being used for saving graphics handles and other data, and the one that your function uses.

Try to rename `handles` in your function to something else, and run again.